# How do I save a model recursively with Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I've been playing with Sequel and Sequel::Model.

I created an `Group` with a many `Items` (one_to_many).

I can do:

```
Group.new << Item.new
```

but not:

```
Group.new.add_item(Item.new)
```

nor:

```
Item.new.group=Group.new.
```

It complains about `Group` not having a primary key.

If I save `group`, it's saved but the items are not saved.

How can I do a recursive  save of everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequel by design does not save entire object graphs.  Its association modification methods are designed to be very direct and not offer a lot of abstraction.

You probably want to use the nested_attributes plugin or the instance_hooks plugin (which the nested_attributes plugin uses internally).

```
# nested attributes plugin
Group.new(:items_attributes=>[{}]).save
```

or

```
# instance_hooks plugin
Group.new.after_save_hook{add_item(Item.new)}.save
```